# meanthemes /meanMenu Links do not have a discernible name

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, performance, jquery-plugins

i need Wordpress support
how fix this problem
Links do not have a discernible name
Link text (and alternate text for images, when used as links) that is discernible, unique, and focusable improves the navigation experience for screen reader users
Failing Elements
a

```
<a href="#nav" class="meanmenu-reveal" style="background:;color:;left:0;right:auto;"><span><span><span></span></span></span></a>
```

i'm use
Wordpress Script, Blog era Pro theme

code on my theme

```
jQuery('.mean-container').prepend('<div class="mean-bar"><a href="#nav" class="meanmenu-reveal" style="'+meanStyles+'">Show Navigation</a><nav class="mean-nav"></nav></div>');
```

and jquery.meanmenu.js

https://github.com/meanthemes/meanMenu

Comment: up up i need hep please